Intermittent File Not Found error in MWAA
I'm running a DAG every minute that gets exchange rates from an API, puts them in a CSV and uploads them to an S3 bucket.
However, intermittently I get this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/airflow/exchange/exchange_rates_20240418141900.csv'
The strange thing is that this is intermittent and usually it works but sometimes doesn't. What could the issue be?
Also if you clear the task it will sometimes work.
DAG code:
def s3_file_upload(ti):
    file_path = ti.xcom_pull(dag_id="exchange_rates_dag", task_ids='transform_json')
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    source_session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=Variable.get('access_key_id'),
        aws_secret_access_key=Variable.get('secret_access_key')
    )

    source_s3 = source_session.resource('s3')

    s3_bucket = Variable.get('s3_bucket')
    source_bucket = source_s3.Bucket(s3_bucket)
    response = source_bucket.upload_file(file_path, 'exchange_rates/{}'.format(file_name))
    print(response) 


Intermittent "File Not Found" errors in MWAA can occur due to the distributed nature of Airflow tasks across multiple workers and the potential inconsistency in file availability across these workers.
If tasks within your Airflow DAG need access to specific files, ensure that these files are stored in a location accessible by all workers, like Amazon S3. See https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-passing-data-between-tasks for more information.
Alternatively, you can utilize Airflow's built-in functionality, such as the Amazon S3 Transfer Operator from the Apache Airflow Providers Amazon package. This operator simplifies the transfer of files from HTTP endpoints to Amazon S3 buckets, ensuring seamless data sharing between tasks. See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/transfer/http_to_s3.html for more information.
